# ngOptions use a later initialized value as result

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have an select with this `ng-options`:

```
res.blob as res.name group by res.title for res in exerciseResources.images
```

the array has such a style:

```
{
    name: "Bee",
    title: "Animals",
    path: "/images/animals/bee_1.2.png"
}
```

The res.blob is initialized during the page load, but it is undefined in html.
On pageload I convert the image into blob which is stored in `.blob` (I refer this in the ng-options).

The init function in the controller refers a function in a service:

```
$q(function () {
    Constants.initBlob();
});
$scope.exerciseResources = Constants.exerciseResources;
```

I think it is loaded afterwards. Is there a way to *refresh the html*, so that the value is working?

Comment: Are you saying `res.blob` is undefined, but `red.name` and `res.title` are not? What does the `exerciseResources.images` array look like?

Comment: are you using it somewhere else later, perhaps `<img src='{{res.blob}}' `? try `ng-src` there.

Comment: yes there its working, but not in the options

Comment: try addng an empty `blob` field to `exerciseResources.images` initially, later replace it same way you're doing now (if you're doing it "outside" angular code, remember to call `scope.$apply()` afterwards)

Comment: then I got `string:`

Comment: can you post the blob loading code somewhere? looks like a scoping issue, or maybe async call. correct me if I'm wrong but `ng-options` should fetch the changes to its source array if triggered properly.